# In ASP.Net Core, no suitable runtime works with package reference Microsoft.AspNetCore.App version 2.1.0-rc1-final

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Summary
I need to reference the new everything metapackage Microsoft.AspNetCore.App version 2.1.0-rc1-final to compile, but no suitable runtime is found.

I tried installing .net core runtime 2.1.0-rc1 but this installed the **.net core** runtime Microsoft.**NetCore**.App and didn't install the **aspnet** core runtime Microsoft.**AspNetCore**.App. Where can I find it or what setting do I need? 
Setting the runtime framework to the 2.1.0-preview didn't work:
2.1.0-preview2-final

### Technical details

I've tried to get rc1 to run on more than one project and I don't understand why a runtime doesn't exist from the sdk installation. `dotnet --info:`

```
Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.2.0-preview1-26503-01
  Commit:  f6bf0a83c6

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.200-preview-007474 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.200-preview-007517 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.200-preview-007576 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.200-preview-007589 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.200-preview-007597 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.200 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.300-preview2-008533 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0-preview2-final [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0-preview2-final [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0-preview2-26406-04 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0-rc1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.0-preview1-26503-01 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

In my Csproj:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.1.0-rc1-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

But when I run, the runtime won't accept the any of the runtimes I have installed. Is a compatible runtime not included in the RC candidate sdk and if not can I force it to run on another runtime. If not, how are other people running release candidates?

```
C:\Users\stick>dotnet "C:\Users\stick\source\repos\Docs\aspnetcore\performance\caching\memory\sample\WebCache\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\WebCache.dll"
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.All', version '2.1.0-rc1-final' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      C:\Program Files\dotnet\
  - Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem:
      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
  - The .NET Core framework and SDK can be installed from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
  - The following versions are installed:
      2.1.0-preview2-final at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
```

Research: [1](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/issues/3) [2](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/pull/29/files) [4](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1252) [5](https://github.com/aspnet/Universe/issues/693)  [6](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/issues/248) [7](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/287) [8](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/issues/255) [9](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/8503) [10](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-microsoft-aspnetcore-app-shared-framework-in-asp-net-core-2-1-preview-1/) [11](https://andrewlock.net/the-microsoft-aspnetcore-all-metapackage-is-huge-and-thats-awesome-thanks-to-the-net-core-runtime-store-2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you updated Visual Studio to version 15.7.1? I had a problem with running asp core app after updated to 2.1.0-rc1-final and I also installed the newest sdk but  the output was:

```
dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450730
```

The solution was to update Visual Studio and now everything works fine.

UPDATE: Now I see, that you haven't installed appropriate SDK and runtime to run this version. You have to install .NET Core 2.1 RC1 SDK and the newest runtime.

Comment: Yes, I updated before I got the error. I ran dotnet manually so that the code exit status you show (may or may not be the same) got displayed as the specific error message output above.

Comment: You have to install the newest SDK from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/sdk-2.1.300-rc1 and also runtime. Sorry, I missed that at first.